# error selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: selenium

I try to search by element name:
login_form = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
login_form.click()

receive this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to introduce explicit wait until that element becomes interactable before clicking it. Try this :

```
login_form = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username")))

login_form.click();
```

Note: Add below imports in your code :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred due to elements are not found correctly, because page is not loaded correctly. So, you can give some time to load page using any one of the following statements.

1) time.sleep(10) 
2) driver.implicitly_wait(10)

```
import time

user_name = "demo.wxyz@gmail.com"
password = "xyz"

login = driver.find_element_by_id("LoginForm_email")
loing_passwd = driver.find_element_by_id("LoginForm_password")
time.sleep(10)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
login.send_keys(user_name)
login_passwd.send_keys(password)
```